# Translate "emptio spei" and "emptio rei speratae" to English

Tags: legal-latin

I would like to have the translation (in context and word by word) of the expressions "emptio spei" and "emptio rei speratae", which are used in Law as types of contracts; *emptio spei* is the type of contract in which you purchase something unsure, something like a trip to see aurora borealis (it doesn't matter if it was raining on that day). The *emptio rei speratae* is a kind of contract in which only the amount of the purchased item is unknown beforehand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Emptio* is a purchase—either the act of purchasing or the thing purchased. It's from the stem of the verb *emō* 'to buy', plus the action noun suffix *-tiō*. The *-p-* is epenthetic, and a regular development between *m* and *t*.

*Spei* is the genitive of *spēs* 'hope; anticipation'. It's an objective genitive, denoting the thing that is bought. *Emptio spei* literally means **'purchase of [a] hope'** or **'purchase of an anticipation'**.

*Rei speratae* is likewise an objective genitive: *rēs* 'thing' is the noun, and *spērātus*, the adjective accompanying it (in the feminine because *rēs* is feminine), is the perfect passive participle of *spērō* 'to hope; to await', obviously related to *spēs*. *Emptio rei speratae* means **'purchase of a thing hoped for'** *or* **'purchase of an awaited thing'**.

The catch here is that Latin doesn't distinguish between merely hoping for something and actively awaiting it, which illustrates the problem of trying to interpret Law Latin jargon by simply translating it.